# Clear react component state on logout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-component

I have a single page app and within it, a react component that loads user data. Upon logging out, this data is persisted. How do I go about clearing the state of this component, apart from clearing my redux state? Is individual component state somehow cleared in the redux reducer as well?

right now I handle the redux clearing of state like so:

// reducers/auth.js

```
export default function authReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        ... 
        case AUTH_LOGOUT_USER:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                // this resets redux state, but not react state?
                isAuthenticated: false,
                isAdmin: false,
                token: null,
                userName: null,
                organization: null,
                logo: null,
                statusText: 'You have been successfully logged out.'
            });
        ...
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

// actions/auth.js

```
export function authLogout() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
    sessionStorage.removeItem('user');
    return {
        type: AUTH_LOGOUT_USER
    };
}
```

// component.jsx

```
...
userData=fetchUserData()
this.setState(userData)
...
```

Comment: Same issue... Did you find a fix?

Comment: @Izzi I think I just moved every data instance to redux. So it all gets cleared now. No more setState with important data.

Answer (score 0):

Just set your `Component` state back to it's initial value within your `logout` function:

```
const logout = () => {
    this.props.authLogout() // your redux action
    this.setState({}) // set this to whatever your initial state is
}
```

Comment: My logout function is kept in an external file and doesn't have access to 'this'... do I need to pass in state or something? (sorry, noob)

Comment: No, just create a wrapper function that does have access to this, which is turn calls your logout function, and also resets state

Comment: I did exactly that, but no luck... My logout function/setState({}) is called from a sibling component... does it need to be in a parent component?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reset redux's store. Component's internal state will be automatically clear when the component unmount.

Comment: but the component is not unmounting. It's a single page app, and the component exists for both logged in and logged out users

Comment: then you are doing wrong. single page app means not all the component were mounted in the same time